# GDB: Error while remotely loading shared libraries

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am using X-server on `Linux tutnix 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu i686 i686 GNU/Linux` .

On X-server i am using schroot to change the root and after that I run my application on it.

Now the problem is I am trying to run `gdbserver`(version 6.7.1) on X-server(say it remote machine) and `gdb`(version 7.7) on Ubuntu machine(local machine or the machine where X-server is running), but its not working.

This is what I tried so far:-

1. executed below commands on remote machine

   - MY_Application &
   - gdbserver localhost:8888 --attach process_id
2. executed below commands on local machine

   - gdb ./MY_Application
   - (gdb)target remote :8888

Now on local machine gdb is showing this message

`Could not load shared library symbols for 20 libraries, e.g. /usr/lib/libqt.so.3.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?`

As far as understand it, gdb is not able to load the shared libraries and there are 20 of them. As a result of this I am not able to find the symbols present in these shared libraries.

I tried to load the symbols from library files on local machine using `symbol-file` command on `gdb` but that leads to address mismatch

So I used the below command

- (gdb)set sysroot remote:/

but it is again showing an error message

`Could not open 'remote:/usr/local/davis/lib/usr/lib/libqt.so.3' as an executable file: Function not implemented`

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? If there is an alternate solution to load the symbols from shared libraries please suggest.

P.S. Both the MY_Application binaries are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for my problem.
The problem was in step 2 shown above. Somehow gdb was not loading all the symbols and PATH to shared libraries. Although PATH shown with `ldd` command was accurate. But still it was not working for me if I simply run the `gdb ./MY_Application`
So I executed one more command after this i.e.

`file MY_Application`

and also copied library file from 
`/srv/chroot/loc/usr/local/davis/lib/`  to  `/usr/local/davis/lib/` after this I connect it to remote server and now it is working fine.